# How can I specify multiple constructors in the case class?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a case class with multiple constructors:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = Something("abc", 100500, _ % 2 == 0)
    val b = Something(true, 10, 20)   
    println(s"$a - $b")
  }
}

case class Something(s: String, n: Int, p: Int => Boolean) {
  /*
  Additional constructor -- Wrong way! -- it is imposible to invoke it outside the class
  def this(b: Boolean, x: Int, y: Int) {
    this("", 0, (i: Int) => i % x + y == 0)
  }
  */
}
```

So far my code doesn't work:

```
Error:(10, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(true)
 required: String
    val b = Something(true, 10, 20)
                      ^
```

To fix it I need to create a companion object to hold an apply function which represents a new constructor for `Something` class:

```
object Something {    
  def apply(b: Boolean, x: Int, y: Int) = {
    new Something(if (b) "" else "default", 0, _ => {
      (x + y) % 2 == 0
    })
  }   
}
```

It is inconvenient. Maybe there is some other way to place multiple constructors into the case class?

Comment: I think companion object is the only way as case class is algebraic type, and it is not supposed to have different forms (different constructors). If you could create auxiliary constructors for it - I don't think it would have played nicely with all case class functionality - like pattern matching

Comment: You mentioned an algebraic type. So I checked in wiki what does it mean and found this: `Each variant has its own constructor, which takes a specified number of arguments with specified types.` So algebraic type allows multiple constructors.

Comment: I think disjoint is meant there: `abstract class Base; case class A(i: Int) extends Base; case class B(s: String) extends Base` Now you can have type with `Integer` or with `String` which is kind of two constructors for `Base`. But it does not look like it solves your problem.

Comment: Martin O. talks about auxiliary constructors [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functional-objects.html#6.7)

Comment: Yes, I know. I read it before. But my question was about case classes.

Answer (score 18):

Actually it works, but you have to use `new` as auxiliary constructors do not have `apply` generated for case class:

```
case class Something(s: String, n: Int, p: Int => Boolean) {
  def this(b: Boolean, x: Int, y: Int) {
    this("", 0, (i: Int) => i % x + y == 0)
  }
}

new Something(true, 5, 5) // Works
```

If you want `Something(true, 5, 5)` to work, you need to create companion object as you said. I think this is because otherwise case class won't be able to work with pattern matching as it is now, or it would have been much more complicated. And notice that pattern matching won't work in this case

Also remember that case class supports default constructors like `case class Something(s: String = "default")` this might help you, but it does not fix your example unfortunately